# Recursive Iterator: Adding child properities to parents in nth level

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I am trying to build a prioritization system so one person can prioritize the list of things the people directly under him has or has not prioritized.  So TheBigCheese has 3 Lackeys under him who in turn have Minions.  Those Minions can also have Minions and the cycle can continue forever.  I want to figure out how I can add the priorities of each Minion (and their Minions) to the priorities of the Lackey because TheBigCheese doesn't care about any of the Minions priorities, he only cares how the Lackey has prioritized his things as well as the things OF ALL MINIONS under him.

```
["TheBigCheese"] => array(
  "myPriorities" => array(),
  "myMinions" = array(
    ["Lackey1"] => array(
      "myPriorities" => array(),
      "myMinions" => array(
        ["Minion1"] => array(
          "priorities" => array(), <--- These need to be added to Lackey1's priorities
          "myMinions" => array()
        ),
        ["Minion2"] => array(
          "priorities" => array(),  <--- These need to be added to Lackey1's priorities
          "myMinions" => array(
             ["Minion3"] => array(
               "priorities" => array(), <--- These need to be added to Lackey1's priorities
               "myMinions" => array()
             )
          ) // End Minion2's Minions
        )
      ) // End Lackey1's Minions
    ),
    ["Lackey2"]  => array(
      "myPriorities" => array(),
      "myMinions" => array()
    ),
    ["Lackey3"] => array(
      "myPriorities" => array(),
      "myMinions" => array()
    )
  ) //End BigWig's minions
);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please show us the result of your function. Before and after.

Comment: @Stewartside There, I think I cleaned it up pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

You need a function to run the recursion and then foreach each top level (199 and 50). Something like this:

```
$myArray = [199 => array(...), 50 => array(...)];
foreach($myArray as &$subArray) {
    $subArray['allChildren'] = recursiveSearch($subArray);
}

function recursiveSearch($array) {
    $allChildren = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $child) {
        $allChildren[] = $key;
        if(is_array($child)) {
            $tempArray = recursiveSearch($child);
            $allChildren = array_merge($allChildren, $temp);
        }
    }
    return $allChildren;
}
```

I haven't tested this works but it should get you on your way.